# Spring boot application returns status 403 if no authentication is sent instead of 401

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-401

I have an API that should return a `401 Unauthorized` status error when an authentication token is missing in the request. However, it currently returns a `403 Forbidden` error instead.

I have a `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class that is responsible for filtering incoming requests and authenticating them based on the presence and validity of a JWT token. If the token is missing or invalid, the filter allows the request to proceed without authentication.

I want to modify the code to ensure that when the authentication token is missing, the API returns a `401 Unauthorized` error instead of the current `403 Forbidden` error. Additionally, I want to exclude certain URLs from authentication, so that they do not return a 401 error.

Logs when I try to request a protected endpoint with no authentication:

```
2023-06-13T14:32:44.524+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/v1/user
2023-06-13T14:32:44.525+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-06-13T14:32:44.535+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-06-13T14:32:44.537+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-06-13T14:32:44.540+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-06-13T14:32:44.541+02:00 DEBUG 5652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Please let me know if you need any additional resources.

`JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

```
package com.user.secretcommander.security;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.getAuthorizationHeader());
        final String jwt;
        final String username;

        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstants.getBearerPrefix())) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(SecurityConstants.getBearerPrefix().length());
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig`:

```
package com.user.secretcommander.config;

import com.user.secretcommander.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // General
            "/",
            // Auth
            "/api/v1/auth/**",
            // Swagger UI
            "/api-docs",
            "/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-ui/**"
    };

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I tried to refactor the following code snippet from the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

```
if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstants.getBearerPrefix())) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
}
```

to

```
if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstants.getBearerPrefix())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
}
```

But then the problem was, that also whitelisted urls (e.g. Swagger UI) were not reachable anymore.

Comment: first of all did you enable TRACE debug logs and read them before you asked here? second, what is the reason for writing a custom filter of something that already exists in Spring Security? whats the point of using a security framework if you dont intend to use its features?

Comment: The TRACE debug logs weren't useful in my case. So I don't need a custom filter?

Comment: The trace debug logs will tell you exactly the reason for why you are getting a 403 but since you have not posted them i cant help you more. And yes, read the spring security documentation, there is an entire chapter named JWT there

Comment: `The TRACE debug logs weren't useful in my case` first of all, what you posted was `DEBUG` logs and not `TRACE` logs, second, and this is why you need to listen to us when we ask for things. For you the logs might not be useful, but when i read the logs i read that you are trying to do a `GET` to the endpoint `/api/v1/user` this fails because you are not authenticated and then the service then redirects you to `/error` but that endpoint is protected too since you have not done n`permitAll`on `/error`.

Comment: you need to read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling to understand how error handling works. Second you have bbeen following some outdated blog post that is very wrong. The filter you have implemented is not only something that already exists, its broken too since it is written in an older version of spring security. I suggest you read this https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1 and here is some heavy commented code https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for your help and staying nice during your answer :)